# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT when trying to make a SMTP connection with net module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, tcp, smtp

Basically I'm trying establish an SMTP connection for an email address with node JS to a remote mx address. here is my code

```
function validate(email) {
  // Extract domain from email
  const domain = email.split("@")[1];

  // Perform DNS MX lookup
  dns.resolveMx(domain, (err, addresses) => {
    if (err || addresses.length === 0) {
      console.log("Invalid email domain");
      return;
    }

    // Connect to SMTP server
    console.log("Found addresses for " + domain, addresses);
    for (let address of addresses) {
      const smtpServer = address.exchange;
      console.log("Checking: ", smtpServer);
      const socket = net.createConnection(25, smtpServer);
      socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("Connected to SMTP server");
        // Send HELO command
        socket.write("HELO example.com\r\n", () => {
          console.log("Sent HELO command");
        });
      });
      socket.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      socket.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
        // Verify recipient email address
        if (data.toString().startsWith("250")) {
          socket.write(`RCPT TO:<${email}>\r\n`, () => {
            console.log(`Sent RCPT TO command for ${email}`);
          });
        }
      });
      socket.on("end", () => {
        console.log("SMTP connection closed");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

when I execute `validate("< a legitimate email >")` I get

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT < an ip address here >
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: < an ip address here >,
  port: 25
}
```

which clearly indicates it is a connection timeout error. Can anyone help me to understand what could be potential reasons for this and also how can I possible mitigate the issue ?

I tried doing some research on some common problems but didn't work. I did following as well

1. Check your network connectivity.
2. Verify the SMTP server address.
3. Try a different SMTP server.
4. Increase the connection timeout.

Comment: Have you verified that you can reach the server from the same host using other programs, i.e. something like netcat, telnet ... ? If you can't do this, then the problem is not in your code.

Comment: Well thanks for your comment. After digging the issue with telnet I figured out the issue. It was actually my ISP that was creating issues. I tested on a different network and it worked.

Comment: However I'm still facing issue after deploying in the aws elastic beanstalk environment. I enabled port 25 in both inbound and outbound rules of the environment. Do you know what could be other reasons ? @SteffenUllrich